# How to import file from other folder Python?

Tags: python, import

My structure is :

```
- Project

  - Configuration
        - __init__.py
        - system.py
  -GUI
        - gui.py
        - __init__.py
```

I would like use `system.py` in `gui.py`.

So I need to import `system` in `gui.py`.
I tried to add `__ init__.py` files by doing:

```
from .Configuration import system
```

but I have the following message : `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I also tried this :

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '../Configuration')

from system import system
```

But it doesn't work either.

How can I do?

Comment: `Project` itself needs to be a package. Create `Project.__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `from Configuration import system`
- `cd .../Project` (Project is current dir)
- `python -m GUI.gui`

`-m options`: python search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module. As with the -c option, the **current directory will be added to the start of sys.path**.

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't work.
What python -m Gui.gui really do ?

Comment: This must work. What error are you getting? Is `__init__.py` empty?